# Why I obtain this JQuery error when I open a WordPress page using a custom theme?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new as **WordPress** developer and I have the following problem.

I have create the template of this website starting from 0 by myself: http://www.asper-eritrea.com

Now I have add this photo gallery plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/robo-gallery/

The problem is that now, when I access to a page that use this plugin, for example: http://www.asper-eritrea.com/photo-gallery/

the gallery is not shown and, into the **FireBug console**, I obtain this error message:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
    $(document).ready(function() {
```

So I think that maybe it could depende by the fact that it can't retrieve **JQuery**, but I am absolutly not sure about it because I have the same error also opening the others page of my website so I am not sure that the missing of JQuery into the photogallery page is the cause of my problem.

Into the **function.php** file of my template I have the following function that enqueue all the JavaScript resources (including JQuery), in this way:

```
/* Hooks a function on to a specific action (an action is a PHP function that is executed at specific
 * points throughout the WordPress Core)
 * @param 'wp_enqueue_scripts': The name of the action to which 'wpb_adding_styles' is hooked (wp_enqueue_scripts
 *        is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that are meant to appear on the front end)
 */
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles');

/* Function automatically executed by the hook 'load_java_scripts':
 * 1) Load all my JavaScripts
 */
function load_java_scripts() {

    // Load JQuery:
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // Load FlexSlider JavaScript
    wp_enqueue_script('flexSlider-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js', array('jquery'), 'v2.1', true);
    // Load bootstrap.min.js:
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), 'v3.0.3', true);

    // Load FancyBox:
    wp_enqueue_script('fancy-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array('jquery'), 'v2.1.5', true);
    // Load scripts.js:
    wp_enqueue_script('myScripts-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    // Load Modernizer:
    wp_enqueue_script('myodernizer-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/modernizr.custom.js', array('jquery'), '2.6.2', true);

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_java_scripts');
```

So what is wrong? What am I missing?

The strange thing is that to enqueue JQuery there is:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

but there is not specified the exact folder of the Jquery source file (as done for the other resources).

I have JQuery putted into the **/assets/bootstrap/js/jquery.js** file.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress generally includes [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which removes the `$` alias to prevent collisions with other libraries that may also be using `$`

Change:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
```

To

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     // OK to use `$` here
```